# how to differ and echo the date using post values

Tags: php

I have a html form from there i post values as 1-3 days, 3-5 days by the header and trying to list all the table values in data table format,but i got struck by displaying the table by date difference. here is my code.

```
    $day = 24*60*60; //seconds 
    $ticket_dates = $UtilObj->get_results("select date1,date2 from tickets where status=1"); 

    foreach($ticket_dates as $dates){

        $datediff = $dates->date2 - $dates->date1;    

       if($datediff > $day)
        {
            $days = round($datediff/$day,0);
        }
        else 
        {
           $days = 1;
        }

       $date_values = str_replace(' ', '', $_REQUEST["status_filter"]);  
            // here its coming as 1-3days,3-5days,..

           if ($date_values  == '1-3days'){            

                    $date_interval = 'and '.$days < 4;

                }else if ($date_values  == '3-5days'){               

                    $date_interval = 'and '.$days < 6;

                }else if($date_values  == '5-8days'){              

                    $date_interval = 'and '.$days < 9;

                }else if($date_values  == 'Above8days'){                 

                    $date_interval = 'and '.$days > 8;

                }else {
                      $date_interval = '';
                    }
        }
```

After this i need to display only the date difference which user select

```
  $myquery = "SELECT t_id,t_date,t_name from t_table where 1=1  $date_interval order by t_id desc;";
```

Thanks in advice

Comment: What is the DATE format of date1 and date2 ?

Comment: its in unix time stamp @ dinuka

Comment: You have to mention at where clause what are you going to filter from the query. What is the column are you going to filter from t_table?

Answer (score 1):

You need the `< number` in the variable so

```
$date_interval = 'and '.$days < 4;
```

too

```
$date_interval = 'and '.$days.' < 4';
```